# Creating sub-boxplots from a continuous data in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, boxplot

I have a continuous data of age and number of cells. I want to group the data by age (say from 0-0.5, 0.5-1, 1-1.5 months and so on...) after which I need to come up with one combined boxplot comparing theses new subsets of data. I have tried to do it by subseting the data into different data frames (say x1, x1, x2...) and then plotted boxplot(x1, x2, x3....). I feel that the process I used is too long and tedious to go through the whole data set. Is there an easier way I can do this? This is part of data

```
Age_month = c(0.6242299795, 1.0513347023,1.1170431211,1.1498973306,1.3141683778,1.3470225873,1.3470225873,1.3470225873,1.3798767967,1.3798767967,
1.3798767967,1.3798767967,1.3798767967,1.4127310062,1.4784394251,1.5112936345,1.5112936345,1.5770020534,1.6098562628,1.6755646817)

Cell_cont = c(4260,1800,5674,7625,3257,5161,2913,3064,8016,3348,5415, 4370,4477,5358,3240,5899,4062,5774,3265,3167)

Dat = data.frame(Age_month, Cell_cont)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cut` to convert a numeric vector into a factor. I am using calculating the breaks on the fly so that you don't have to hard code your group boundaries.

```
cutAgeMonth = cut(Age_month, breaks=seq(from=0, to=ceiling(max(Age_month)), by=0.5))
Dat = data.frame(cutAgeMonth, Cell_cont)
boxplot(Cell_cont ~ cutAgeMonth)
```